# Failed assertion : boolean expression must not be null

Tags: flutter, dart

I am new to flutter, and whenever I am trying to add new images from the app it shows me 'boolean expression must not be null'. How should I fix it?

```dart
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return (load || load1)
    ? loader2
    : SafeArea(
      child: WillPopScope(
        onWillPop: WillPopMethod,
        child: Scaffold(
          body: SingleChildScrollView(
            child: columnUserProfile(
              languageList,
              id,
              name,
              list,
              indexSelected,
              complaints,
              gate,
              booking,
              residence_id,
              paymentStatus,
              status,
              widget.phone,
              gender,
              widget.societyName,
              apartment_name,
              residence_name,
              vehicles),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
}
```

Comment: what are the values of `load` and `load1`?

Comment: bool load =  true;
  bool load1 =  true;
@TirthPatel

Comment: can you post all the code?